# Android Kotlin: Hilt how to get object of Application class?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

Here i created application class dependency. now i want to access

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class MyApplicationModule {
    @Provides
    fun providesMainApplicationInstance(application: MainApplication): MainApplication =
        application
}
```

**My application class is:**

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MainApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
    }

    fun printData(){
        Log.d("Test","Awesome print data")
    }


}
```

**i want to call printData() function from the activity.** i have used field injection to access application class but it gives error...

```
@Inject lateinit var mainApplication: MainApplication
```

**ERROR**

```
[Dagger/DependencyCycle] Found a dependency cycle:
 MainApplication is injected at MyApplicationModule.providesMainApplicationInstance(application)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class MyApplicationModule {

    @Provides
    fun providesMainApplicationInstance(@ApplicationContext context: Context): MainApplication {
        return context as MainApplication
    }
}
```

Hilt can inject application context. You need to simply cast it.

Let me know if it's good.

Answer (score 3):

Hilt auto generate `ApplicationContextModule.java`, which provides both `Context` and `Application`.